# Lambda function referenced pointer destroyed detection

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, detection

I create a lambda function to run code in a different thread or simply to run it a bit later, but it can happen that an object kept by the lambda function is deleted in the mean time.

How can I detect that and not run the function in that case?

for instance

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    virtual void test(){std::cout << m;}
    int m;
};
int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    std::function<void ()> function = [=]()->void
    {
        //if( pointer to 'a' still valid )
        {
            a->test();
        }
    };
    delete a;
    //or if( pointer to 'a' still valid )
    function();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

or the detection could be done before executing the lambda function too.

An other idea is to have an object "Runnable" keep the lambda function and register it to the one that can be deleted. Then in the destructor I would notify the Runnable and prevent the execution.

Would that be a good way to do it ?

Comment: Do not use raw pointers, and use `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: You should be setting `a=NULL` after you invoke `delete`. Then you can do `if (a != NULL) DO SOMETHING`.

Comment: using a shared ptr would keep the object alive until the execution, but I need that object to be deleted when required.

Setting the variable to null doesnt change the value inside the lambda function

Comment: you can also use std::weak_ptr to have a pointer that can be checked if you have other pointers to this object and convert to smart pointer when needed (and fails graceully, if an object was deleted in the mean time, you need to use it with smart_ptr's, not raw pointers though. [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

Comment: @Tuxdude would that work? Doesn't the lambda have a copy?

Comment: @Tuxdude: That's a very crude method to prevent abuse of a single pointer to the deleted object. It won't help if there are other pointers to the same object, such as the copy captured by the lambda. You need smart pointers to track object ownership reliably.

Comment: I'm not much familiar with lambda functions, but I have to agree you're right - it would have just a copy. But if you could pass the address to the variable a within the lambda function, I feel you can overcome it. Since I dont know the syntax of lambda functions, I'm not even sure if it is doable :)

Comment: @Tuxdude it's doable, but you want weak pointers here.

Comment: Passing the address of the variable doesn't work, because the variable is probably going to go out of scope around about the point where it is deleted.  Even if it doesn't, the other thread might check it for `nullptr`, then the variable is deleted, then  the other thread uses it (a classic race condition).  No: you are sharing the ownership of a pointer, you really should use `shared_ptr` and its little brother `weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test whether the object pointed by the pointer has been deleted or not..

If it has been deleted, your test() would just have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
std::weak_ptr<A> weak_a(a);
std::function<void ()> function = [weak_a]()->void
{
    if( std::shared_ptr<A> a = weak_a.lock() )
    {
        // to get the A* from a, do a.get()
        // operator-> and *a work however:
        a->test();
    }
};
a.reset(); // instead of delete
```

The use of the `weak_ptr` is optional -- if you instead made it a `shared_ptr` copied to the lambda, the lifetime of `a` would be extended by the lifetime of the lambda.

This does require that the code that uses `a` outside of the lambda be `shared_ptr` compliant.